# Geolocation only works with https, $.getJSON only without it. What can I do?

Tags: jquery, getjson, codepen

I'm working on a pen at codepen.io in Chrome. I need both coordinates (navigator.geolocation) and weather data from an api ($.getJSON). After some googleing I figured out how to make the former work - by opening the page with https:// But as soon as I did that, the latter stopped working. What can I do and why is that?